# QGIS hyperlink to specific row/column excel

Tags: qgis, excel, hyperlink

Is there a way to set a hyperlink to a specific sheet/row/column in an excel document? I am able to link to an excel file on the server and open it from QGIS, but would like to open the document to a specific sheet or row within the excel document. Is there a specific modifier on the file path needed?